# Request to Spring Controller returns 404 not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I am trying to set up a Spring MVC app but every time I call the http://localhost:9001/tasks API from postman I get the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TaskManagerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TaskManagerApplication.class, args);
}


@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        }
    };
}
}
```

TaskRepository:

```
@Path("tasks")
@ApiIgnore
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaskResource {

private final TaskService taskService;

@GET
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
    return taskService.getTasks();
}
```

TaskService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TaskService {

private final TaskRepository taskRepository;

public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return taskRepository.findAll();
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `JAX-RS` in spring boot. Spring handles rest in its own way, if you want to use `JAX-RS` instead of Springs Rest Annotations, you need to do some extra configurations.

First, you need to add a `JAX-RS` dependency in your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` file. I guess you have already done that. Jersey is one of the `JAX-RS` implementation, if you want to add this, you need to do the following.
`build.gradle`

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey"
```

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After that, you need to register the `JAX-RS` endpoints with Spring. I guess you missed this step.

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JaxrsConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JaxrsConfig() {
        register(TaskResource.class);
    }
}
```

After this, your `JAX-RS` endpoints will be registered with spring.

But I will suggest you to follow spring annotations if you are using spring. If you use spring annotations your code will look like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "tasks")
public class TaskResource {

    @GetMapping(path = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<String> getAllTasks() {
        return Arrays.asList("a","b");
    }
}
```

Also you will need to remove JAX-RS from spring to use this Spring MVC annoatations to work.